# How to prove that $ L_\lambda(s):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{\lceil k^{1/\lambda}\rceil^s}$ converges for $\Re(s)>0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Consider the following series, where $\lambda\in(0,1]$ and $s\in\mathbb{C}$
$$
L_\lambda(s):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{\lceil k^{1/\lambda}\rceil^s}.
$$
It is easy to see that $L_\lambda$ converges absolutely in the half plane $\Re(s)>\lambda$. And intuitively, I think it should converge conditionally if $\Re(s)>0$; this would be the case if we had $k^{s/\lambda}$ instead of $\lceil k^{1/\lambda}\rceil^s$ in the denominator. However, I can't seem to find a way to prove this. What I tried: by the estimate
$$
|\sum_{k=m}^M\frac{(-1)^k}{\lceil k^{1/\lambda}\rceil^s}|\leq |\sum_{k=m}^M\frac{(-1)^k}{k^{1/\lambda}}|+|\sum_{k=m}^M\frac{(-1)^k(\lceil k^{1/\lambda}\rceil^s-k^{s/\lambda})}{\lceil k^{1/\lambda}\rceil^s k^{s/\lambda}}|
$$
we see that $L_\lambda$ converges if $\Re(s)>\lambda/2$. But how proceed if $\Re(s)\leq\lambda/2$? I also tried to somehow apply ideas similar to the alternating series test to the real part and the imaginary part of $L_\lambda$, but this proved extremely messy. And At first sight I thought this can't be too difficult to show, as we only pass from $k^{s/\lambda}$ to $\lceil k^{1/\lambda}\rceil^s$, which shouldn't make that much of a difference. Any ideas?

Comment: If $s\in]0,\infty]$ then it is clear since $$\frac1{\lceil k^{\frac1\lambda}\rceil}\le \frac{1}{k^\frac1\lambda}$$.

Comment: The series converges for $\operatorname{Re} s > 0$ by Dedekind's test.

Answer (score 2):

The convergence for $\operatorname{Re} s > 0$ follows easily from Dedekind's criterion

> Let $(a_n)$ be a complex sequence with bounded partial sums, and $(b_n)$ a complex sequence of bounded variation — i.e. $\sum \lvert b_n - b_{n+1}\rvert < +\infty$ — converging to $0$. Then $\sum a_nb_n$ converges.

This follows via summation by parts. Apply this with $a_k = (-1)^k$ and $b_k = \lceil k^{1/\lambda}\rceil^{-s}$.

Another way to prove this is by Cahen's theorem that the region of convergence of a Dirichlet series is a half-plane, noting that $(k+1)^{1/\lambda} - k^{1/\lambda} \geqslant 1$ for $\lambda \in (0,1]$, so no denominator $n^s$ occurs more than once, and the convergence for $0 < s$ by the alternating series test.